# Complex match and Join PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have the below 3 tables:
Opening transactions, closing transactions and another one with prices (or quotes).

Opening and closing are mirror images of each other. If one is BUY the other is SELL. They are matched by the same txn_id.

```
INSERT INTO opening_txns (txn_id,txn_timestamp,cust_txn_type,exch_txn_type,currency,amount) VALUES 
('0001','2019-01-16 09:00:00.000','SELL','BUY','Euro',1000)
,('0002','2019-01-25 09:00:00.000','BUY','SELL','Euro',1000)
,('0003','2019-01-30 09:00:00.000','BUY','SELL','Euro',1000)
,('0004','2019-02-06 09:00:00.000','SELL','BUY','Euro',1000)
,('0005','2019-02-12 09:00:00.000','SELL','BUY','Euro',1000)
,('0006','2019-02-25 09:00:00.000','BUY','SELL','Euro',1000)
,('0007','2019-03-21 09:00:00.000','BUY','SELL','Euro',1000)
;

INSERT INTO closing_txns (txn_id,txn_timestamp,cust_txn_type,exch_txn_type,currency,amount) VALUES 
('0001','2019-03-29 12:00:00.000','BUY','SELL','Euro',1000)
,('0002','2019-03-29 12:00:00.000','SELL','BUY','Euro',1000)
,('0003','2019-03-29 12:00:00.000','SELL','BUY','Euro',1000)
,('0004','2019-03-29 12:00:00.000','BUY','SELL','Euro',1000)
,('0005','2019-03-29 12:00:00.000','BUY','SELL','Euro',1000)
,('0006','2019-03-29 12:00:00.000','SELL','BUY','Euro',1000)
,('0007','2019-03-29 12:00:00.000','SELL','BUY','Euro',1000)
;

INSERT INTO bc_quotes (quote_timestamp,currency,unit,quote_type,"quote") VALUES  ('2019-02-25 09:00:00.000','Euro',1,'SELL',1.1375) ,('2019-02-25 09:00:00.000','Euro',1,'BUY',1.1355) ,('2019-03-21 09:00:00.000','Euro',1,'SELL',1.1416) ,('2019-03-21 09:00:00.000','Euro',1,'BUY',1.1392) ,('2019-03-29 12:00:00.000','Euro',1,'BUY',1.1225) ,('2019-03-29 12:00:00.000','Euro',1,'SELL',1.1246) ;
```

I am looking for the below outcome:

- txn_id
- amount
- sell_price (Find which one of opening or closing txns is a SELL cust_txn. Match the currency, timestamp and exch_txn_type of that transaction with currency, timestamp and quote_type in the bc_quotes table and pick the quote)
- buy price (Find which one of opening or closing is a BUY csut_txn. Match the currency, timestamp and exch_txn_type with currency, timestamp and quote_type in the bc_quotes table and pick the quote)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is assuming the columns of `opening_txns` and `closing_txns` are of the same type.

Please try the following and tell me if it works for you:

```
WITH txns AS (
  SELECT
    txn_id,
    amount,
    currency,
    timestamp,
    exch_txn_type
  FROM opening_txns
  UNION
  SELECT
    txn_id,
    amount,
    currency,
    timestamp,
    exch_txn_type
  FROM closing_txns
)
SELECT
  txn_id,
  amount,
  CASE WHEN cust_txn_type = 'SELL' THEN quote ELSE NULL END AS sell_price,
  CASE WHEN cust_txn_type = 'BUY' THEN quote ELSE NULL END AS buy_price
FROM txns T
  LEFT JOIN bc_quotes Q 
    ON (T.currency = Q.currency AND T.timestamp = Q.timestamp AND T.exch_txn_type = Q.quote_type);
```

Explanations:

- `txns` is a [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html) to help clarify the query.
- Since both `opening_txns` and `closing_txns` share the same columns,
  you can use `UNION` to effectively merge two results sets into one
  `txns` result set.
- Then you can use `LEFT JOIN` to match the rows of
  `txns` to their respective quotes using the conditions provided in
  the `ON` clause.
- Lastly, you can use the conditional `CASE` statement
  in the `SELECT` to distinguish between `'SELL'` and `'BUY`
  transactions; if the transaction is a `'BUY'` (resp. `'SELL'`), then
  the `buy_price` column will be `quote` and `sell_price` will be
  `NULL`.

The final result set has the following columns: `txn_id`, `amount` and `sell_price`, `buy_price`.

I hope this helps.